# Spring Boot with server.contextPath set vs. URL to hystrix.stream via Eureka Server

Tags: spring-cloud, turbine, hystrix, netflix-eureka

I have Eureka Server with Turbine instance running and a few discovery clients that are connected to it. Everything works fine, but if I register a discovery client that has `server.contextPath` set, it didn't get recognized by `InstanceMonitor` and Turbine stream is not able to combine its `hystrix.stream`.

This is how it looks in the logs of Eureka/Turbine server:

```
2015-02-12 06:56:23.265  INFO 1 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Hosts up:3, hosts down: 0
2015-02-12 06:56:23.266  INFO 1 --- [        Timer-0] c.n.t.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor   : Url for host: http://user-service:8887/hystrix.stream default
2015-02-12 06:56:23.268 ERROR 1 --- [InstanceMonitor] c.n.t.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor   : Could not initiate connection to host, giving up: []
2015-02-12 06:56:23.269  WARN 1 --- [InstanceMonitor] c.n.t.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor   : Stopping InstanceMonitor for: user-service default

com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$MisconfiguredHostException: []
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor.init(InstanceMonitor.java:318)
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor.access$100(InstanceMonitor.java:103)
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$2.call(InstanceMonitor.java:235)
    at com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceMonitor$2.call(InstanceMonitor.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It tries to get hystrix stream from `http://user-service:8887/hystrix.stream` where the correct URL including sever.contextPath should be `http://user-service:8887/uaa/hystrix.stream`

The `application.yml` of that client contains:

```
server:
  port: 8887
  contextPath: /uaa

security:
  ignored: /css/**,/js/**,/favicon.ico,/webjars/**
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

**My question is:** should I add some additional configuration options to this user-service discovery client to register proper hystrix.stream URL location?

I didn't dig into that yet, I will let you know if found something before getting answer to that question.

### Current solution

There is one problem when it comes to using `server.contextPath` and `management.context-path`. When both are set, turbine stream is being served on `${HOST_URL}/${server.contextPath}/${management.context-path}/hystrix.stream`. In that case I had to drop using `server.contextPath` (I replaced it with a prefix in controllers `@RequestMapping`).

Now, when you user `management.context-path`, then your hystrix.stream is being served from the URL that uses it as a prefix. In that case you have to follow Spencer's suggestion and set

```
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix=/{PUT_YOUR_MANAGEMENT_CONTEXT_PATH_HERE}/hystrix.stream
```

And of course this `management.context-path` must be set with the same value for all your Discovery Clients - it can be done easily with Spring Cloud Config http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.<CLUSTERNAME>=/uaa/hystrix.stream`.  Where `<CLUSTERNAME>` is the value set in `turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig`.  All of the config options from the [Turbine 1 wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine/wiki/Configuration-%281.x%29) work.  You don't need to add the port to the suffix as Spring Cloud Netflix Turbine adds the port from eureka.

Comment: Hey Spencer, thanks for your answer, I gotta check it shortly. Quick question - would it cover a situation, where I have a few running instances, each one with different context path set?

Comment: It should be, with a different `<CLUSTERNAME`>.

Comment: Hey Spencer, I used your suggestion to find workaround to the problem I run into. The problem is that `server.contextPath` and `management.context-path` mix together if it comes to creating url to hystrix.stream. I had to drop using `server.contextPath`, I described it in the initial post. Take a look for more information. Thanks!