# Turbine doesn't know contextPath of each application through Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine, netflix-eureka

When deploying Spring Cloud-enabled microservices on JBoss, we have to use a contextPath. Turbine doesn't seem to fetch the contextPath from eureka and eureka doesn't seem to ask it to the microservices.

Some more details:

Every microservice has its own Jboss, and its own contextPath defined in the war, as such:

```
hostname1:port1/products
hostname2:port2/users
hostname3:port3/orders
```

Endpoints (actuator and our own) are exposed after the contextPath (not using management.context-path):

```
hostname1:port1/products/env
hostname1:port1/products/info
hostname1:port1/products/books
hostname1:port1/products/books/123
```

Eureka only cares about the hostname and port. It allows us to define a different UrlPath to info and health although this is not part of the data Turbine needs to get to hystrix.stream:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    statusPageUrlPath: ${server.contextPath}/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: ${server.contextPath}/health
```

Is there a way to tell Turbine which contextPath is used for which application? These are different per application so a cluster-wide fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471547/spring-boot-with-server-contextpath-set-vs-url-to-hystrix-stream-via-eureka-ser) wouldn't be sufficient I suppose.

Comment: I turbine "cluster" is for instances of a service, so all of "products" or "users", so it should work for your case.

Comment: Since clusters cannot be aggregated into a single stream, it would mean ops need to have a dashboard open for every type of microservice. Is that manageable in your experience? Would the dashboard perhaps only be looked at during deployment of a specific cluster?

Comment: You can only view one cluster at a time in normal turbine.  With https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp we aggregate all statistics via rabbitmq (not http), so you can see everything at once.

Comment: Wow great piece of information! I'd like to accept your comment as answer but I don't think that's possible.
Well either way thanks for the fast and helpful feedback Spencer :)

Comment: moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only view one cluster at a time in normal turbine. With [spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp) we aggregate all statistics via rabbitmq (not http), so you can see everything at once.