# Netflix Turbine does not create correct service url if context-path set

Tags: spring, cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix, turbine

We use Eureka discovery and have multiple services running inside docker behind Zuul.

Our Turbine service, also behind Zuul, is unable to connect to the service instance if the service has a context-path set.

The url path is created in `SpringClusterMonitor` using the host and port but without any context-path.

Is it possible to add this functionality or override the `SpringClusterMonitor` as a bean?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518250/966698).

If your 'context-path's are different for services, then you should have config like this:

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: SERVICE1,SERVICE2,SERVICE3
  appConfig: SERVICE1,SERVICE2,SERVICE3
  instanceUrlSuffix:
    SERVICE1: /service1/hystrix.stream
    SERVICE2: /service2/hystrix.stream
    SERVICE3: /service3/hystrix.stream
```